# Confusion Over Google's GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have just been looking at the GWT and i am impressed by what i have seen but i do not really understand how it is used to when creating web applications.

For example, when im programming in PHP or JSP creating a simple app that lets users register, adds the detailes to a database and then allows them to login is pretty simple but i was wondering how GWT does this?

When doing this in GWT, would GWT widgets be used to construct a frontend(client) that accepts user input and then sends it to a server which is written using pure Java, the Java then does all of the data processing and database interfacing?

If my understanding is correct, is GWT just a way to write javascript frontends in an easier way?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into the [GWT Overview](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html)? I think this line explains it the best:

> The GWT SDK contains the Java API
>   libraries, compiler, and development
>   server. It lets you to write
>   client-side applications in Java and
>   deploy them as JavaScript.

Basically, you write your code in Java, all the while using the GWT to create complex UI's, etc. When you "compile" it, it is highly optimized JavaScript that translates well to multiple browsers, including web platforms.

Whatever language you want to use server-side does not matter - ASP.NET, PHP, etc - it will all work with GWT because GWT is, ultimately, JavaScript.

Basically, Google is trying to make it simple to develop web applications in a familiar language, and doing all the underlying work for you. I'm sure there is someone else who can further expand on the capabilities and advantages of GWT, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Exactly. "[In the end, it's just JavaScript](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/learnmore-sdk.html)", you can "[Use the backend language of your choice](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/learnmore-sdk.html)"